# Linear transformation for matrix using Einstein convention

Tags: matrices, inner-products, transformation, convention

I feel like I am stuck. How can I interpret the equation with Einstein summation? Here is the exercise:

> you should see that r′ can be written as a linear transformation of r. This means we should be able to write r′=Ar for some matrix A.

The exercise is depicted on the picture.

I will be more than thankful if someone explains that to me in minute detail. 
[image]

Comment: Seems to me that you’ve already been given step-by-step instructions for solving this problem. The only additional step that you’ll need to perform is expanding the resulting expression for $\mathbf r'$ in coordinates and picking out the coefficients to form the matrix.

Comment: That's exactly that I can't solve out. I know what the Einstein summation states, but I can't understand how I can interpret r' when it's determined by the equation. Could you help me please?

Comment: No, as I am trying to solve it interpret it with Einstein summation.